# How to copy a directory to google cloud storage using google cloud Python API?

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

The following function serves well for copying a single file to the google cloud storage.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.5
import googleapiclient.discovery

from google.cloud import storage

def upload_blob(bucket_name, source_file_name, destination_blob_name, project):
  storage_client = storage.Client(project=project)
  bucket = storage_client.get_bucket(bucket_name)
  blob = bucket.blob(destination_blob_name)

blob.upload_from_filename(source_file_name)

print('File {} uploaded to {}.'.format(
    source_file_name,
    destination_blob_name))
```

Now instead of giving a filename, i tried inputting a directory name, `upload_blob('mybucket','/data/inputdata/', 'myapp/inputdata/','myapp')` 
but then i get this error:

> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'read'

Do i need to give any additional parameters when calling the function `blob.upload_from_file()` to copy a directory?

Comment: is file uploading working fine??

Comment: Yes it is working great.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here's some code you can use to accomplish this:

```
import os
import glob

def copy_local_directory_to_gcs(local_path, bucket, gcs_path):
    """Recursively copy a directory of files to GCS.

    local_path should be a directory and not have a trailing slash.
    """
    assert os.path.isdir(local_path)
    for local_file in glob.glob(local_path + '/**'):
        if not os.path.isfile(local_file):
            continue
        remote_path = os.path.join(gcs_path, local_file[1 + len(local_path) :])
        blob = bucket.blob(remote_path)
        blob.upload_from_filename(local_file)
```

Use it like so:

```
copy_local_directory_to_gcs('path/to/foo', bucket, 'remote/path/to/foo')
```

Where `bucket` is the usual object from the Google Cloud Storage API:

```
from google.cloud import storage    
client = storage.Client(project='your-project')
bucket = client.get_bucket('bucket-name')
```

Comment: What type of object is the "bucket" parameter in the function? Is it a string?

Comment: @DominiquePaul it's a bucket object returned by the Cloud Storage Python API.

Comment: Needing to iterate your own files to copy a directory seems like something the API should just handle for users. It's perhaps the second most common usage pattern and would be part of nearly anyone's end to end application needing programmatic access to GCS. I consider it bonkers that this is not just a built in capability of the API.

Answer (score 8):

Uploading more than one file at a time is not a built-in feature of the API. You can either copy several files in a loop, or you can use the command-line utility instead, which can copy whole directories.